# How to avoid browser warning while self sign a SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I plan to deploy my own hardware device maybe in form of a RaspberryPi running a NodeJs server which should include HTTPS communication. It is intend to run as an intranet device and it will always named with the same computername (or same IP address if necessary). Let us say stephan.box.

What is the best practice to equip such devices with encryption to ensure secure wireless lan HTTP  communication?

Is it possible to self sign a a SSL certificate for a static IP or domain name to avoid browser warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only avoid browser warnings if the issuer of the certificate or the certificate itself is trusted by the browser. If you create a certificate which is self-signed or if you use a private CA you must import this CA into ALL browsers which should access the system or accept the warning once in ALL browsers. The only way to avoid this is a CA which is already trusted by the browsers, that means buying a certificate (some CAs give also simple certificates away without costs).